# Prevent Duplicate Insertion on DB When page refresh - Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, duplicates, postback, records

(ASP.NET) 
How do i prevent duplicate records insertion in my database when user refreshs the page after post back. i know it can handle by redirecting the page. it and also handle through the check if same entry exists inside the stored procedure. but this wont full fill requirement sometime. i just want to know is there any other good practice instead redirecting the page. 
(I know it can also handle using AJAX, but i am not using AJAX)

Comment: You can use [IsPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            do something

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page.IsPostBack property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //logic 
    }
}
```

In the code example above, if the page is a postback then no code would be executed (the logic).